# SQL: Detect multiple same entries as a batch

Tags: mysql, sql, string, group-by, mysql-5.7

The use-case is a follows. When I have multiple entries with same content, the results should be somehow clubbed together depending on the exact data except some important key.

```
------------------------------------
| student_id  | subject_id | marks |
------------------------------------
| STD001      | SUB001     | 10    |
| STD001      | SUB002     | 20    |
| STD002      | SUB001     | 10    |
| STD002      | SUB002     | 20    |
| STD003      | SUB001     | 11    |
| STD003      | SUB002     | 20    |
| STD004      | SUB001     | 11    |
| STD004      | SUB002     | 20    |
| STD005      | SUB001     | 11    |
| STD005      | SUB002     | 20    |
| STD005      | SUB003     | 30    |
------------------------------------
```

Expected final result

```
-------------------------------------------------
| subject_id_str       | marks_str | student_id |
-------------------------------------------------
| SUB001_SUB002        | 10_20     | STD001     |
| SUB001_SUB002        | 10_20     | STD002     |
| SUB001_SUB002        | 11_20     | STD003     |
| SUB001_SUB002        | 11_20     | STD004     |
| SUB001_SUB002_SUB003 | 11_20_30  | STD005     |
-------------------------------------------------
```

OR

```
--------------------------------------------------------
| subject_id_str       | marks_str | student_id_str    |
--------------------------------------------------------
| SUB001_SUB002        | 10_20     | STD001_STD002     |
| SUB001_SUB002        | 11_20     | STD003_STD004     |
| SUB001_SUB002_SUB003 | 11_20_30  | STD005            |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

> More Info: Using MySQL 5.7

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you facing solving this problem

Comment: Tried with group by, multiple join, lost track of how many ways - sorry that I didn't mention any approach.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string aggregation:

```
select
    group_concat(subject_id order by subject_id separator '_') as subject_id_str,
    group_concat(marks      order by subject_id separator '_') as marks_str,
    student_id
from mytable
group by student_id
```